# GridView item text not changing colour

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gridview

I'm trying to change the text colour of specific items in my grid view but for some reason it is not working. Everytime I launch my app the text colour for all my gridview items remain white, which is not the outcome I expected despite the code used. Does anyone know what has gone wrong and what needs to be done in order to resolve this problem?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;

    static final String[] years = new String[]{
            "1863", "1864", "1868", "1871", "1890",
            "1898", "1900", "1906", "1968", "1979"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.gridview_item, R.id.item_gridview, years);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_gridview);

    if(position == 4 | position == 6){
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1e1eff"));
    }
    else if(position == 2){
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e32017"));
    }
    else {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }


    return tv;
}
}
```

**layout/gridview_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show us how you implement your adapter ?

Comment: You will need to create a custom ArrayAdapter.. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: I forgot to mention, gridview and listview adapters can be used interchangeably if written generically. You can refer that adapter to create your own, it will have the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to initialize your layout, and custom adapter

**UPDATE**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;
    public MyAdapter adapter;
    static final String[] years = new String[] {
        "1863", "1864",  "1868", "1871", "1890",
        "1898", "1900", "1906", "1968", "1979"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        for (int i = 1; i < years.length; i++) {

            adapter.addAdapterItem(new AdapterItem(years[i]));
        }
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < AdapterItem > {
        private List < AdapterItem > items = new ArrayList < AdapterItem > ();

        // private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textviewid) {
            super(context, textviewid);
        }

        public void addAdapterItem(AdapterItem item) {
            items.add(item);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public AdapterItem getItem(int position) {
            return ((null != items) ? items.get(position) : null);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                rowView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_item,
                    null);
            } else {
                rowView = convertView;
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_gridview);
            tv.setText(items.get(position).first);
            if (position == 4 || position == 6) {

                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1e1eff"));
            } else if (position == 2) {
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e32017"));
            } else {
                // tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

            return rowView;
        }
    }

    public class AdapterItem {
        public String first;

        // add more items
        public AdapterItem(String first) {
            this.first = first;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work after using your suggested code. Should `parent, false` be used instead of `null`?

Comment: Try LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gridview_item ,  parent, false);

Comment: `Cannot reslove method 'getContext()'`

Comment: are you using getView() inside your MainActivity?